Time tracking of user, how much time he/she use the application : Flutter
I am currently researching how to track user activity time within an application. While attempting to implement this in Flutter, I encountered some issues which I will outline below. If you have any solutions or alternative approaches for this task, please let me know.
I tried tracking user activity time using Flutter's lifecycle states. However, I encountered a problem: when the app is moved to the background and then killed or removed from recent tabs, no state or activity methods are invoked.
To address this, I implemented the tracking on the native Android side, as the onDestroy method is called in every case when the app is killed. I then tried to integrate this with Flutter using a method channel. While the onDestroy method is invoked on the native side and logs are recorded, the Flutter activity is destroyed before the Flutter code can be executed.
The goal is to avoid frequent time checks and instead simply record the start time, end time, pause time, and resume time, from which the total usage time can be calculated.
If anyone has a solution for this issue or can provide guidance on how to achieve this, please let me know.
I just expecting that i got the time duration of a user that he/she used the application for this time duration.

Related: Android Activity onDestroy() is not always called and if called only part of the code is executed and Flutter exact lifecycle equivalents to onResume / onPause on Android and viewWillAppear / viewDidDisappear on iOS

Please be aware that in the case of a crash, there is no way for any of your code to be called, so anything happening in an onDestroy, onPause, onResume, etc will not occur.  This is why assuming cleanup methods will run is generally a bad idea.  A better way to do this would be to set a timer in your app to run every few seconds, and update the time spent to disk.  Then cancel the timer in onDestroy.

Also please note that onDestroy is called when the Activity is deemed "over".  This is not the same as when the Activity is no longer on screen, and can be minutes in the future.  onStop is probably more appropriate if you were to do it that way.

[https://pub.dev/packages/time_tracker] (Time Tracker)
So i saw this package a while ago, this works on screen level , but maybe by modifying source code of this package you can achieve , your goal :)
